# Looping and storing different length of obj in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I am trying to iterate in an array

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And I want to store them in an object so that:

```
[
   {1},
   {1,2},
   {1,2,3},
   {2,3,4},
   {3,4,5},
   {4,5,6}
]
```

As you may notice, the first element to be pushed in the array is removed first if the limit of 3 was reached.

I'm doing this:

```
var given = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var limit = 3;
var start = 1;
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < given.length; i++) {
  var j = 0;
  while(j <= start) {
    j++;
    if(start <= limit) {start++};
    result.push(given[i]);
  }
};
console.log(result);
```

Seems like my answer is super wrong, i'm still stuck at pushing it 1 by 1 then increase. So i haven't yet, think of replacing the oldest element.

**EDIT:**

Also I'm thinking of not shifting the array and put the new value to the end instead replace the value and maintain their indexes...

i mean

```
[
    {1},
    {1,2},
    {1,2,3},
    {4,2,3},
    {4,5,3},
    {4,5,6}
]
```

Comment: Did you leave out `[4, 5, 6]` by accident, or is it intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var given = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var limit = 3;
var start = 1;
var result = [], rec = [];
for (var i = 0; i < given.length; i++) {
    rec = rec.slice(0);
    if(rec.length == limit){
        rec.shift();
    }
    rec.push(given[i]);
    result.push(rec)
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/68k6C/)

O/P

```
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

**Update**

```
var given = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var limit = 3;
var start = 1;
var result = [],
    rec = [];
for (var i = 0; i < given.length; i++) {
    rec = rec.slice(0);
    rec[i % limit] = given[i]
    result.push(rec)
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mqMuM/)

O/P

```
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[4,2,3],[4,5,3],[4,5,6]]
```